Can I control the CSS of VS code through an extension?
I'm trying to make a plugin for VS code to help me teach a beginners python class. I'm trying to get it to highlight part of the VS code UI, so that I can say something along the lines of "Click here to commit the changes you made in this file".
So far, I'm able to highlight the <h1 id="inside_iframe">I'm in UR base</h1> element, but the rest of the elements are outside the iframe that the extension is living in.
I assume I'm taking entirely the wrong approach to this problem. Is there a more productive avenue to try?
const vscode = require('vscode');


/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "ariadne" is now active!');

    const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('ariadne.changeCss', async function () {
        const selectors = [
            '.monaco-editor', 
            '.activitybar', 
            "#workbench.parts.titlebar",
            "#workbench\.parts\.activitybar > div > div.composite-bar > div > ul > li:nth-child(2)", // the search icon in the actions container
            "#inside_iframe"
        ]; // Example selectors
        const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
            'cssChanger',
            'CSS Changer',
            vscode.ViewColumn.One,
            {
                enableScripts: true
            }
        );

        panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent(selectors);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

function getWebviewContent(selectors) {
    return `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>CSS Changer</title>
            <script>
                const selectors = ${JSON.stringify(selectors)};
                let index = 0;

                function applyCss() {
                    if (index < selectors.length) {
                        const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selectors[index]);
                        console.log(index, selectors[index], "", elements);
                        elements.forEach(el => el.style.outline = '2px solid red');
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            elements.forEach(el => el.style.outline = '');
                            index++;
                            applyCss();
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                }

                window.onload = applyCss;
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1 id="inside_iframe">I'm in UR base</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
    `;
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}

